# Ant build multiple EAR projects

Tags: ant

I want to be able to have one set of build/props files that will build as many EAR projects as I tell it to.
Each EAR project will have its own set of modules, WARs, JARS, etc.
I'm want to set in a props file what each EAR project consists of, and I want to tell the build each time which EAR(s) to build.
In general, what is a good way to structure the build/props files?
So far, I have one build.xml file and one props file.
In the props file, I have an entry for each EAR project, for example:

```
Foo=fooWar, foojar
Bar=barWar, barJar1, barJar2
```

Not sure if that's a good idea or not, and I'm thinking how to tell the build which projects to build.
Since it could be many projects, I'm thinking I would want another props entry like:

```
projectsToBuild=Foo, Bar
```

And then before each build, the build person would edit "projectsToBuild".
Is this a good road to go down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building multiple projects in one hit, then it sounds like you don't have any proper dependency management in place. Have a look at using [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to publish and retrieve from a shared repository (e.g. [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php)), so that you can decouple your project and build them independently.